# Formatting wordpress debug messages

Tags: server, debug, hosting

On my local PC (win 8 & IIS) when I get a wordpress debug message I get a nicely formatted table at the top of the page with a full stack trace.

When I enable debugging on my linux hosting I just get a single line outputted without any wrapping  so half the message is hidden by the admin menu.

Obviously my local PHP is running in development mode but is there a way to make my hosting output nicely formatted debug message that I can read easily?

Comment: You could install Debug Bar on the remote. This plugin will provide a debug button top right that will contain errors. It's also has a wide range of useful extensions and is free. Worth a shot.

Comment: Are you by chance using a server package like xampp on your Windows box? These tend to bundle a debug module like xdebug, which give you the "nice" error messages - you can install it on your linux box too, but this is way outside the scope of WPSE and you'll be better off asking on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Yes, it must be xdebug making the nice tables.  Is there anyway to just wrap the error message in a <div> so it doesn't get obscured by menu?